# How to make lockout screen script for ubuntu

Tags: scripts, cron, lock

how to make lockout script for Ubuntu. basically I want to create script and schedule it (cron) and I want computer to lock screen everyday in:
13:00
14:00
16:40

any help would be nice. 
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dbus` for that.

The script you looking for is simply

```
#!/bin/bash
 DISPLAY=:0
 qdbus com.canonical.Unity /com/canonical/Unity/Session com.canonical.Unity.Session.Lock
```

Save that , make it executable, and run a cron job that calls this script at the times you want